# Connecting a Command Handler to a Button inside a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have hunted and cannot find an answer so I turn to the experts. I apologize for the length but without seeing everything I believe it is hard to put into context.

In a WPF window I have a tab control. The number of tabs is decided by the number of items in a List. Each tab has 3 TextBoxes, a ScrollViewer and 3 buttons. I am NOT using MVVM. The binding for the TextBoxes and ScrollViewer are fine. I cannot seem to figure out how to get a Button Command handler hooked up. I have even tried the most simple, creating a RoutedCommand and using that as demonstrated [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands). One thing I noticed is I cannot "see" these buttons from IntelliSense.

I have a ButtonCommand class derived from ICommand:

```
class ButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public ButtonCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public ButtonCommand(Action<object> execute,
                       Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a button handler class:

```
class ButtonHandler : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ButtonCommand StartButtonClicked { get; set; }

    public ButtonHandler()
    {
        StartButtonClicked = new ButtonCommand((o) =>
            {
                int x = 1; // just something to put a breakpoint on
            },
            (o) =>
            {
                return true;
            });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I just cannot figure out what I need to do to get this hooked to my button!

```
<Window x:Class="TestOfScrollGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="this"
        Title="MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestOfScrollGrid"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid Name="mainGrid">
        <TabControl Name="tbcTraceTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelTraceMsgList, ElementName=this}" >
            <!--  This section controls the top tab  -->
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="TabItem">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChannelName}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!--  This section controls the content  -->
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="300" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Margin="3,10,1,10"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                               Content="Mode:" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                               Margin="0,10,2,10"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Content="Test ID:" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="4"
                               Margin="0,10,2,10"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Content="ODM Status:" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbxTestMode"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Width="120"
                                 Height="23"
                                 Margin="2,10"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Background="Green"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 Text="{Binding TestMode}"
                                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbxTestID"
                                 Grid.Column="3"
                                 Width="120"
                                 Height="23"
                                 Margin="2,10"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Background="Green"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Text="{Binding TestId}"
                                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbxODMStatus"
                                 Grid.Column="5"
                                 Width="150"
                                 Height="23"
                                 Margin="2,10"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                 Background="{Binding BoxColor}"
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Text="{Binding OdmConnectedString}"
                                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />

                        <ScrollViewer Name="sv_TraceScrollViewer"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelTrace}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=MsgIn.Msg,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay}"
                                                           TextAlignment="Left" />
                                            </Border>
                                            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                                                    BorderThickness="1">
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=MsgOut.Msg,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay}"
                                                           TextAlignment="Left" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" x:Name="spButtons"
                                    Height="60"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button x:Name="btnStart"
                                    Width="70"
                                    Height="40"
                                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                    Command="{Binding StartButtonClicked}"
                                    Content="Start" />
                            <Button Name="btnNext"
                                    Width="70"
                                    Height="40"
                                    Margin="10,0"
                                    Content="Next" />
                            <Button Name="btnCancel"
                                    Width="70"
                                    Height="40"
                                    Margin="10,0"
                                    Content="Cancel" />
                            <Button Name="btnClose"
                                    Width="70"
                                    Height="40"
                                    Margin="10,0"
                                    Content="Close"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you bind an instance of the ButtonHandler class to the view? What is the DataContext of the TabControl? {Binding StartButtonClicked} will bind to the Codebehind or the DataContext instance

Comment: Good question, Pascal! That is the question. Where DO I bind the ButtonHandler to the view? Though, this is not a MVVM type pattern. The DataContext of the TabControl, I believe is set by using the ItemsSource Statement in the XAML. There is also a dependency property set on the List: public static readonly DependencyProperty ChannelTraceMsgListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChannelTraceMsgList", typeof(ObservableCollection<ChannelTraceData>), typeof(MainWindow));